# Book Is/Was Divided Into Sections

Tags: tense, past-tense, usage

Suppose a book consists of three sections:

> The book ***is/was*** divided into three sections.

I am thinking the past tense option "*was*" should be used, because the act of dividing the book into three sections happened at the time of writing.
Is my analysis good?

Comment: and is divided no more, and would be divided no more as well?

Comment: I don't think there is direct pointing to the time of writing here. Look, " the cake was divided into three pieces" - is it about of the time of cooking or later?

Comment: The present tense in conjunction with the past participle of a transitive verb can refer to a *resulting state*.  The cow is milked because the cow has been milked. The race is run because the race has been run. The house is painted because the house has been painted. The cake is divided into eight pieces because the cake has been divided into eight pieces.  The question is answered because the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the context. If, for example, you were using divided as a past tense verb, like this:

> The book was too long, so it was divided into three sections

Then *was* is fine.

However, if you are *describing the format* of a book, like this:

> This book is divided into three sections

The *divided* is used in the past participle, ie a verb made into an adjective, so we use *is*, just as with any other adjective.

Comment: Is it correct to write "the population ***is divided*** into three ethnic groups" even though there is no external agent doing the dividing?

Comment: Yes - it's the past participle again.

Comment: I understand the result-sense of "*divided*".  But, it is not like a population could be divided into ethnic groups on a whim.  The ethnicity of the individuals could not be changed to suit some ethnicity-based division scheme.

Comment: Regardless of _when_ x was divided, assuming it is _still_ divided you use _is_.

Comment: Maybe there is a sense of "*divided*" that I cannot find in the dictionary.